# How to copy files from AWS EFS To AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I want to migrate data from AWS EFS to S3?

The total number files required from migrations are huge and will lead to data in TB

What is the best approach to copy files from EFS to S3?

Answer (score 2):

@Gauri, you can either use S3 Sync, run the job in screen to sync files. For those reading who are not familiar with [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) the syntax for S3 Sync is like:

`aws s3 sync /pathtosource/ s3://bucketdestination/`

Also you can use `s3fs` to mount bucket in your Server and run rsync job in screen.

Comment: hi, would you mind explaining in more detail what I would have to replace `pathtosource` with please? I have an EFS volume which I'd like to copy over to my s3 bucket but I can't figure out what `pathtosource` should be. Thx

Comment: never mind, that was a silly question. For anyone stumbling upon this, `pathtosource` is just your efs directory which should already be mounted on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

1) Please check the below [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datasync-transfer-efs-s3/). use DataSync to transfer data.

2) Other approach can be

```
aws s3 sync /sourcepath/ s3://dest
```

3) AWS data Pipeline